# syntax error with trivial picasso example in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm trying a trivial example with Picasso in Android Studio (2.2.2):

If I type the following line, 'with' stays red and the tooltip shows "Cannot resolve symbol '**with**'"
         `Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

But if I type the following line, studio auto completes on the 'with' when I type Picasso.w

`Picasso foo = Picasso.with(this);

If I type `Picasso.`, the only auto-complete choices are Builder, Listener, LoadedFrom, ...

So clearly Visual Studio knows about the class definition (If I right->Inspect Code... on Picasso, it opens Picasso.java, and that file does contain

`public static Picasso with(Context context) { ... }`

What am I missing?

(I have the following in the dependencies block in my build.braddle)
 `Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView)`

Comment: Is your code in a method or a class body?

Comment: what type is `this` in this context?

Comment: Please add your code with question.

Comment: Thank you @laalto. I was out of a method. I was so focused on the tree that I missed the forest.